# How can I create an updating directory log in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

The goal of this script is to create a log file if it does not exist, or update the existing log file if it does exist of the directory that the user inputs when the program is run. My problem is that I cannot find a way to compare the log file with the current state of the directory while still being able to update the log file properly, and display each file that is being added to the screen. This is the code I am using so far:

```
userinput=$1
if [ ! -d "$userinput" ];
then
        echo "Usage: dirlog.sh directory_name" 1>&2
        exit 0
else
        if [ ! -f "$userinput.log" ];
        then
                ls -l > $userinput.log
                echo ".logfile created for $userinput"
        elif [ -f "$userinput.log" ];
        then
                if [   ];
                then
                        echo "$file missing from directory $userinput"
                else #file not missing
                        echo "no files missing from directory $userinput"
                fi
                #Update this no matter what
                ls -l > $userinput.log
                echo "logfile updated for directory $userinput"
        fi
fi
```

Comment: Sorry not getting you.Elaborate more your problem.

Comment: I would suggest the following: 

 - can you clarify what the script is intended to check? "$file" is defined nowhere
 - your if and elif test should read;
    [ -f ${userinput}.log ];
  as is, they are testing for a variable called "$userinput.log" which has not been defined.